# nightwatch inject javascript, doesn't return the focus to the next element on the web page

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I'm using setValue to enter over 300 chars and nightwatch's setValue keys in char by char which is slow. I tried .execute function to inject custom javascript on to the page. I see the value is set on the page but the focus remains on the text box. what can I do to get the focus out so that I can continue.

application is using reactjs

## sample code:

```
    browser.execute(function(elementId){
    document.getElementById('elementId').value = 'chars .............'
  },[],function(result) {
      console.log("element is set");
 });
browser.click('.elementID-1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with performing click on something out of that text box just to lose focus from that element and see if it is working.